# Dynamic source code in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, evaluation

How to process dynamic source code in C++? Is it possible to use something like eval("foo")?

I have some functions that need to be called depending on user's choice:

```
     void function1 ();
     void function2 ();
     ...
     void functionN ();

     int main (int argv, char * argv [])
     {
         char * myString = new char [100];
         ...
         myString = "1" //user input            
         cout << eval("function"+myString)();
     }
```

How is it usually done?

**UPD**: Based on slacy's and clinisbut's answers I think I need to make a function registry. I suppose it should be made as an array of pointers to functions. Here's the question, how do I declare an array of pointers to functions?

Comment: I know you're asking specifically regarding dynamic code - but the scenario you presented is usually handled with a switch statement - nothing dynamic involved. I assume the options as to which function to call are limited.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++ is a compiled language, and thus, there is no equivalent to "eval()".

For the specific example you mention, you could make a function registry that maps inputs (strings) to outputs (function pointers) and then call the resultant function.

There are several C++ interpreter libraries that are available, although performance will be very poor, they may accomplish what you want.  Google search for "C++ interpreter".  I've seen results for "[Ch](http://www.softintegration.com/)", "[CINT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint)" and "clipp"

Comment: However, you could dynamically invoke the compiler, tell it to produce a DLL, load that DLL and pull out and invoke your dynamically compiled function. I would be *very* slow, but you could do it (assuming that your application will run in an environment that has a compiler and linker available to it).

Comment: If you wanted something faster and crazier, you could assemble the machine instructions yourself in a buffer and then call the buffer through a function pointer... though that would be basically impossible to do correctly and would be *very* platform specific.

Comment: note that even on dynamic languages, using eval() would be much, much slower than the sane solution.

Comment: clipp is not a C++ interpreter, rather it's an embedding framework that makes it possible to use other interpreted languages with c++ code.  It includes an interpreter for javascript.

Answer (score 17):

The real answer to your question is this:

```
extern "C" {
void function1 ();
void function2 ();
void function3 ();
}


 int main (int argv, char * argv [])
 {
     char * myString = new char [100];
     ...
     myString = "function1"; //user input     

     void (*f)() = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, myString);
     f();
 }
```

You can obtain the function defined in your binary (by its name, if it was declared with extern "C"), and call it.

On windows, it becomes uglier, but still possible - read on GetProcAddress

Comment: Didn't slsym() return a void*? C++ requires a reinterpret_cast< > for that conversion.

Comment: +1, this is actually an answer to the original problem. Compiling C++ on the fly looks like overkill when you just need to setup a function pointer. First answers on SO have an unfair advantage...

Answer (score 7):

You could [embed a C/C++ interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_interpreter) into your program if you really need this. However, you could also [embed a more script-like language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) instead.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question of how this is usually done, the answer is: it isn't.

Having to use something like `eval()` is usually a design problem. If you really do need it, embed a scripting language such as Lua or Python.

Answer (score 4):

If you put function1 .. functionN in a DLL, you could simply pull them out and invoke them by name using dlopen/dlsym which would probably get you 90% of the way you want to go.

Answer (score 4):

How about function pointers?

Answer (score 2):

The C++ language itself is not able to do that directly. But you may use plateform specific functions to call any function in a given DLL, according to user input (or whatever). For example, on Windows, look for GetProcAddress() and LoadLibrary()

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case for embedding an interpreted language like LUA. If you create LUA bindings to your C++ API, you'll be able to dynamically execute your code via LUA code from your application.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this :

1. **Dynamic Loading**

   - Windows: `GetModuleFileName()` with `hModule = NULL` this gives the path of the executable.
     Use `LoadLibrary(Executable_Name)` to load itself in the memory.
   - Linux : Use `dloopen()` with `NULL` and it loads itself in memory.

   In both Windows and Linux you can define a `void* (function*)()` pointer. This always works with all signatures without parameters. This does not work on class methods.
2. **Using Namespace System**

   This namespace would be easy you can use the `Inspect` functionality and `InvokeMember` methods to dynamically call class methods and access variable from inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in C++. It is a mandatorily-compiled language.

A lot of information that would be necessary to implement eval() is lost at run-time anyway.

Comment: The C++ Standard nowhere forbids implementation of C++ via an interpreter, which could implement an eval()-style function. The function itself would of course be non-standard.

Comment: It is not possible since there's no reflection in C++.
Your eval() wouldn't be able to fruitfully communicate with the rest of your (compiled) code.

Comment: There is nothing in the C++ Standard that says that C++ implementations cannot support reflection, either.

Answer (score 1):

I would build an array, or an STL list, of function pointers and the strings that you find that trigger the call to them. If you really need to call an arbitrary function you should investigate RTTI  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information

Comment: How will RTTI help identify the types of function pointers, which are not polymorphic types?

Comment: True, but all I intended was to provide a starting point. I don't believe "doing his homework for him" is as valuable as giving him a pointer to where he can learn for himself.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I declare an array of pointers to functions?

**The C programmer's response to this question:**

use cdecl.

> cdecl> declare functable as pointer to
> function (int,pointer to int)
> returning double
>
> double
> (*functable)(int , int *)
>
> cdecl> declare functable as array 17 of pointer to function (int) returning double
>
> double (*functable[17])(int )

Note that functions automatically convert into pointers to functions, in the same sense that arrays decay into pointers. You don't need an & to take the address of a function to put it in a pointer.

If you're in C++, it might help to use a std::map<*YourFunctionPointerType*> instead of an array, since you want to map strings anyway...

**The OO approach:**

Use polymorphism instead. It doesn't immediately solve your problems, but there's a good chance that if you're doing this it makes sense to have a class for each function.

Note that a vtable is, fundamentally, a table of pointers to functions.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science)).  It's not supported by default in C++, but many people have written comprehensive reflection systems for all sorts of purposes.  One that comes to mind off the top of my head is binding C++ functions to a custom scripting language.

Others have mentioned using a switch statement (or more accurately and if/else tree).  This is about as simple as a reflection system is likely to come... and it is probably the best solution for your project.  Reflection in C++ is a fairly advanced technique and often requires a lot of additional code... sometimes even custom preprocessors.

Also note that for security purposes, eval() is almost never something you want to be using in any language.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to embed and eval code within a C++ application is probably to use a scripting language like python. Use [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/python/doc/index.html), "a C++ library which enables seamless interoperability between C++ and the Python programming language."