# Executing strings in c++

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic source code in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895077/dynamic-source-code-in-c)

is there anything in c++ that executes strings? like in python, there are `exec`, and to some extent `eval`

Comment: Nothing in the standard libraries, no.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no.

I don't know if this exceeds your needs,

http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/proto/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

C# can do something like this, but i dont believe c++ can with standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As C++ is a compiled language, there is no possibility to evaluate/execute runtime-generated code. Of course, you could send such code to a C++ compiler at runtime and start a new process using the built binary. But I think that would not address your purpose.